# Edit typescript before angular compiler

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-compiler, angular-builder

I want to strip a ts code before angular compiler.
Here is how it looks like before the compilation:

```
...
 /* prod:start */
 const title: string = "Production title!"
 /* prod:end */
 /* dev:start */
 const title: string = "Dev title!"
 /* dev:end */
```

To strip ts code i'm using [webpack-remove-block-loader](https://github.com/bytefunc/webpack-remove-block-loader) loader in custom-webpack configurations

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'webpack-remove-block-loader',
            options: {
              active: true,
              blocks: excludedClients.blocks,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    ...
```

To make custom-webpack works i'm using [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) with this config in **angular.json**:

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js",
              "mergeRules": {
                "module": {
                  "rules": "prepend"
                }
              },
    ...
```

The problem is that it doesn't work. If i remove **enforce: 'pre'** flag from custom-webpack config for loader that strip ts code - it'll remove blocks of code from already compiled ts files, that's wrong, otherwise with **enforce: 'pre'** it should works before angular compiler, but it doesn't, code is still have comments for both types of build(prod/dev).

And yes, i know that it's possible to use options from `environment.ts` files but it's not flexible enough.
Thanks!

Comment: Since your goal seems to be to manage different build configurations, I strongly suggest to use the `configurations` section in the `angular.json` file. You can define file replacements for different `environment.xxx.ts` files there. https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-target-specific-file-replacements

Comment: @derpirscher as i wrote, i know about this ability, but it's not what i want. I need to strip blocks with parts of routes/imports/object properties and so on. As an example you need to use one or other component depends on build configuration(`angular.json`). In this case you can use `environment` properties(if/else), but you also need to remove an import of component that you don't need, otherwise angular compiler will compile unnecessary code(component/module)